# windows authentication in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2003

So, i have my virtual directory with Anonymous Access disabled. I allow users to login to my app through the windows server login.
I wish to know how i can, through the code, capture the username that is logging in.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HttpRequest.Current.User.Identity.Name` or simply `User.Identity.Name` if you are in a `Page` should give you the name of the user currently logged in.